# Crystal report printing to wrong printer

Tags: vb.net, crystal-reports, report

I'm troubleshooting an issue with a VB.NET app that I inherited.

The following lines execute print operation:

```
Me.rptShippingLabel1.PrintOptions.PrinterName = "LabelPrinter"
Me.rptShippingLabel1.PrintOptions.PaperOrientation =   CrystalDecisions.Shared.PaperOrientation.Landscape
Me.rptShippingLabel1.PrintToPrinter(Me.txtLabelQty.Text, False, 1, 1)
```

There is a `Zebra` `ZDesign` `TLP2844` connected to workstations via direct `USB` and named `LabelPrinter`. However, despite target printer being specified in the code, that Zebra must be set as default printer in Windows, otherwise the job would go to any other printer set as default.
What's even more frustrating is that on some computers, with exactly the same configuration jobs go to correct printer but I can't identify controllable pattern.
Any suggestions why might that be?

Reports in question are disassociated from printer in Design>Page Settings.

Comment: The printer name has to be exactly what it is called on that computer.  The same printer on different computers can have a different name.

Comment: @Steve - it is spelled out right on each and every workstation and in the code.

Comment: Have you confirmed that using the "Printers" collection? This holds all the printers installed on the local computer and you can get the "Name" that needs to be given to the "PrinterName" for Crystal.

Comment: @Steve - working on it right now using System.Drawing.Printing.PrinterSettings.InstalledPrinters()

Comment: @Steve - yes, got collection of installed printers. LabelPrinter is there. I even added extra chars to listing strings to catch hidden trailing spaces (if any).

Comment: This may be a classic Crystal Reports bug (there are many of them). What version of runtime do you use?. Check this http://scn.sap.com/thread/3292416 it may help.

Comment: @Steve - The original code was compiled to NET 2.0 and some very old CR runtime but I recompiled it to CR 13.0.5 As a test I tried to get report.PrintOptions.PrinterName after I just had set it and display it in a label but I'm getting an empty string...

Comment: Old thread but I think I've got the same issue.  Did you get it sorted?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look into your report. In page settings see if report is optimized for display. If yes, uncheck it. If report is optimized for displaying only, PrinterOptions enumeration is being discarded. You could still assign to Printer name property in older framework but not anymore.

Comment: How do you get to these page settings?

Comment: @Paul Right click on the *.rpt file> Design> Page Setup, uncheck "No Printer (optimize for screen display)"

Answer (score 3):

Try the following code

```
    Dim rptShippingLabel1 As New CrystalReport1
    Dim PrinterSettings1 As New Printing.PrinterSettings
    Dim PageSettings1 As New Printing.PageSettings

    'Replace it with your printer name
    PrinterSettings1.PrinterName = "Microsoft XPS Document Writer"
    rptShippingLabel1.PrintToPrinter(PrinterSettings1, PageSettings1, False)
```

to get the printer name, don't read it from rptShippingLabel1.PrintOptions.PrinterName it will show blank. Try reading from PrinterSettings1.PrinterName.

This is tested with Crystal Reports runtime 13.0.9